# pandas/numpy/pure python - vector addition performance

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

I compared how long it takes to add two vectors in `pandas`/`numpy`/pure python and got some surprising (for me) results.

Tested on python3.6.9, Ubuntu 18.04, numpy=1.18.1, pandas==1.1.3.

### CODE

```
import pandas as pd                                                             
import numpy as np                                                              
import random                                                                   
from timeit import timeit                                                       
                                                                                
repeat = 1000                                                                   
max_exp =7                                                                      
                                                                                
def time_all(a, b):                                                             
    sa = pd.Series(a)                                                           
    sb = pd.Series(b)                                                           
                                                                                
    na = np.array(a)                                                            
    nb = np.array(b)                                                            
                                                                                
    py_sum = lambda: [x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)]                              
    pd_sum = lambda: sa + sb                                                    
    np_sum = lambda: na + nb                                                    
                                                                                
    py_time = timeit(py_sum, number=repeat)                                     
    pd_time = timeit(pd_sum, number=repeat)                                     
    np_time = timeit(np_sum, number=repeat)                                     
                                                                                
    return py_time, pd_time, np_time                                            
                                                                                
for i in range(2, max_exp):                                                     
    size = 10 ** i                                                              
                                                                                
    a = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(0, size)]                        
    b = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(0, size)]                        
                                                                                
    py_time, pd_time, np_time = time_all(a, b)                                  
    py_pd = round(py_time / pd_time, 4)                                         
    py_np = round(py_time / np_time, 4)                                         
    pd_np = round(pd_time / np_time, 4)    
                                     
    print('''                                                                   
ARRAY SIZE: {}                                                                  
    PY/PD: {}                                                                   
    PY/NP: {}                                                                   
    PD/NP: {}'''.format(size, py_pd, py_np, pd_np))
```

### RESULT

```
ARRAY SIZE: 100
    PY/PD: 0.0357
    PY/NP: 8.656
    PD/NP: 242.1978

ARRAY SIZE: 1000
    PY/PD: 0.3286
    PY/NP: 44.3758
    PD/NP: 135.05

ARRAY SIZE: 10000
    PY/PD: 2.8774
    PY/NP: 69.2828
    PD/NP: 24.0785

ARRAY SIZE: 100000
    PY/PD: 11.7784
    PY/NP: 76.5296
    PD/NP: 6.4974

ARRAY SIZE: 1000000
    PY/PD: 26.2985
    PY/NP: 33.1973
    PD/NP: 1.2623
```

### QUESTIONS

1. For small arrays (up to ~5k elements) python is more efficient than pandas, for very small the difference is big. Is there any general rule what operations have (so much) better performance on pure-python than pandas? Something like "for less then 100 rows pandas will be order of magnitude slower whatever you do"?
2. As far as I understand, pandas internally uses numpy. Do those performances differ only because of conversion time between pd.Series and np.array? If yes, is there any way to force the conversion when Series is created?
3. (least important, but most surprising) For 10^6 array pure python was ~ 77 times slower than numpy, but for 10^7 the ratio is only 33. Why?

Comment: Nothing too surprising.  `numpy` is fastest (when starting with arrays).  For very large arrays relative performance drops because of memory management complications.  `pandas` uses numpy arrays, but has added overhead keeping track of row indices (and possibly more).

Answer (score 0):

Anyway this code can be written in vectorial algorithm, and in this case numpy will give to you a speedup of over 1000> for large amount of data.